# Using Spring OAuth2 client with the github api

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to use Spring Security OAuth2 to access the github api. The problem I'm having is that once you get a response from their authorize api, you don't get back a token, you get back a code that needs an extra verification step.

I don't see how I can plug this into spring's oauth 2 framework. Am I missing something?

Here's the flow github wants:

[github oauth](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/)

This step specifically:

If the user accepts your request, GitHub redirects back to your site with a temporary code in a code parameter as well as the state you provided in the previous step in a state parameter. If the states don’t match, the request has been created by a third party and the process should be aborted.

Exchange this for an access token:

POST https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token

Answer (score 0):

You can plug that in Spring Security. That is called the `authorization code` and Spring Security supports that.

Here is the chapter in the specs where this *extra-step* flow is described: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1

You don't have to care about this. Spring will *automagically* handle that behind the scenes. Here is the class in Spring Security that handles that flow: `AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider`